# How to associate RX/TX of the BLE RN487x with a LED?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, script

I assembled the scheme suggested by Microchip for the Bluetooth Low Energy BLE model RN4871, pointed out in the schematic of FIGURE 5-4 of the Datasheet (page 26). I've connected a led to Pin 12 (P0_2) and set the BLE as UART transparent, according to User Guide (page 59, topic 4.2 UART TRANSPARENT CONNECTION).

According to the manual, it's necessary to associate the I/O Port with a number that identifies the Service Handle. But, when BLE is as UART Transparent, I can't list the Services and their Handlers by de command "LS".

Question: How do I create a script to make the LED blink when I receive (or send, whatever) data via RX/TX?

USER GUIDE:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002466B.pdf

DATASHEET:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002489C.pdf

PICTAIL:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002547A.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but after reading the manual I kind of get the feeling that the scripting capability can only be used when the RN4871 is **NOT** in UART_TRANSPARENT_MODE. Maybe you have to check with someone at Microchip?

Comment: I also think that's it, but it's not clear in the datasheet. I also don't have much experience with BLE, so I hope someone who knows can guide me. I already posted the same issue in the Microchip Forum. Thanks!